# No sound from headphones ubuntu 13.10 on iMac

Tags: sound, 13.10, mac, alsa, headphones

I have a fresh ubuntu on iMac. I have managed to set up the sound from the native speakers, however, there is still no sound from the headphones. I have disabled automute in alsamixer, but this didn't help. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: Maybe you could manually change your output device in All Settings / Sound?

Comment: I did that already -- no positive result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found by adding a row of `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12043359).

[image]

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04. Thx! Here some additional infos: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto